# jQuery obtain value from input field inside TD (HTML Table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have an HTML Table like the following.

```
<table id="items">    
    <tr class="total_up"> 
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
        <td class="total-value" id="total"><div id="total">$875.00</div></td>
    </tr>             
    <tr class="disc" id="disc">    
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Discount</td>
        <td class="total-value" id="discount">
            <div id="discount"><input type="text" name="disco" class="dis"></div>  
            <input type="button" id="discount" name="apply" value="apply"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the value of the input field with class=dis to a Javascript variable. I already tried the following, but failed.I am a noob in jQuery.

```
$("#items #disc").val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#disc` is a `tr`. The `input` has the class `dis`. Try like following.

```
$("#items #disc .dis").val();
```